# Syntax error AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a table with an auto increment primary key so I do:

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE Home" +
                       "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                       " name VARCHAR(255), " + 
                       " value DOUBLE PRECISION, " + 
                       " data DATE " + 
                       " )";
```

The problem is that when I executee this query I obtain:

```
Syntax error AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) did you find auto_increment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no `auto_increment` in PostgreSQL. Use `serial` instead.

Your create table statement should be:

```
create table Home (
   id serial not null primary key,
   name varchar(255),
   value double precision,
   data date
);
```

[Here's updated documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype.html) on full set of PostgreSQL data types.

Take a look at [this DB-FIDDLE](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xppUdabtsyQy5eyM5fP8aD/0) with the exact same working example.

Comment: it's not work and the error is the same! Syntax error serial

Comment: @Doflamingo how on earth can this answer fail?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using PostgreSQL v10 or later, you might want to use the standard conforming *identity column* syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE home (
   id integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   name varchar(255),
   value double precision,
   data date
);
```

Apart from standard compliance, it has the advantage that you get an error message if you try to explicitly add a value for the `id` column, which is usually a mistake that will lead to collisions with future auto-generated values.